# How do I turn this array of objects into a string using ES6 methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of objects:

```
const pagesByBook = [
{bookName: "An old tome", pages: 123},
{bookName: "Really ancient stuff", pages: 432},
{bookName: "Yup, another old book", pages: 218}
]
```

And I would like to get the following string output:

```
        const output= "['An old tome', 123, 'old', null],
        ['Really ancient stuff', 432, 'old', null],
        ['Yup, another old book', 218, 'old', null]"
```

How can I do this using in a few lines using ES6 methods such as map?

Comment: Maybe.  Have you tried anything?  DId you get stuck somewhere?

Comment: You already mentioned the best method...did you try it?

Comment: Why that weird string format? Can't you just use JSON?

Comment: Where does that `'old'` come from, is that a constant?

Comment: @Bergi: I guess 'old' could be a constant. Regarding the weird string format, I don't know, because I need to output like a string. I don't know how I could do that with JSON. If it works the same then I'm ok with that possibility.

Comment: @nicokruk Construct an array that has the structure of the output you expect, i.e. `[['An old tome', 123, 'old', null],
        ['Really ancient stuff', 432, 'old', null],
        ['Yup, another old book', 218, 'old', null]]`, using a loop or `.map()`. Then call `JSON.stringify()` on that array to get a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to get your required result.

```js
const pagesByBook = [{
    bookName: "An old tome",
    pages: 123
  },
  {
    bookName: "Really ancient stuff",
    pages: 432
  },
  {
    bookName: "Yup, another old book",
    pages: 218
  }
]

const res = JSON.stringify(pagesByBook.map(item => Object.values(item).concat("old", null))).slice(1, -1);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me to be a simple `map` with ES6 destructuring. Assuming that the last 2 elements in the arrays are constants (`old`, `null`):

```js
const data = [ {bookName: "An old tome", pages: 123}, {bookName: "Really ancient stuff", pages: 432}, {bookName: "Yup, another old book", pages: 218} ] 

const result = data.map(({bookName, pages}) => [bookName, pages, 'old', null])

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

If a string representation of this is needed you could change it to:

```js
const data = [ {bookName: "An old tome", pages: 123}, {bookName: "Really ancient stuff", pages: 432}, {bookName: "Yup, another old book", pages: 218} ] 

const result = data.map(({bookName, pages}) => JSON.stringify([bookName, pages, 'old', null]))

console.log(result.join(','))
```